# C# child thread is still working even main thread exit

Tags: c#, multithreading

I happened to read Semaphore class sample as below from msdn:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

It's a console app, however something confused me that child threads are able to work even main thread exits.
[image: threads]

From my understanding, when main thread/process exits, all child threads will be terminated, that's why usually we signal and wait child threads to finish before main thread stops.
Am I wrong or the behaviour has been changed in .net due to reference?

Comment: It is really not about main and child threads, but about foreground and background threads. Any active foreground thread will keep the process alive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the child thread to abort on the termination of the parent thread, it must be set as a Background thread.

```
t.IsBackground = true;
t.Start(i);
```

Otherwise, all foreground threads run to completion before the process exits

Comment: Thanks, it's a concept introduced in .net.